# Google cloud print - print multiple copies

Tags: php, printing, google-cloud-print

I have a problem with google cloud print api. I can't find an example for adding capabilities to a a printer (specifically multiple copies to a printer LaserJet Pro P1102w). 
I used https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/proxyinterfaces#register this as reference, but it didn't help me much. It only describes what response should be like, and i can't get anything similar to that.
If I use "list" on my google account - printers, I don't get any capabilities listed as part of my printers.
If anyone has any idea what to do, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If your software is the one calling the register API, then you can create a [CDD](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd) to represent the capabilities of your printer. In the CDD, you can specify that the printer supports the "copies" capability. The reason why you don't see the capabilities in the /list API call is because it's a large field and is omitted from /list and /search calls (exception: /search call with q=^recent will return capabilities). Try using the [/printer](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appInterfaces#printer) API to retrieve a printer's capabilities.

Once you've registered your printer with the copies capability, specify how many copies to print in the "ticket" parameter of the /submit API.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, call the API multiple times? I know almost nothing about API's, but try something like this:

```
$num = number of copies wanted;
while ($count < $num) {
call API;
count++;
}
```

Comment: I thought about this too but, this means multiple requests to the server. Which can be bad when sending big files. That's why it's best to use the built in way.